# After execution Call back function program doesnt return to orignal execution?

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suppose I have following program :

```
Global Variables
void  main (..)
{
  declared nodes.. and stuff

  while(1)
  {
      do X stuff.. 

      publish a topic..
  }
} 

void callback()
{
    process data.. 
}
```

I am not able to publish a topic, after first call back is called.. Is it some error in my code or, I am missing some return statement.. ?

Actually am using [Odometry Sample Program](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom) and have linked it with roserial program. So the only modification to sample odometry program I have made is that have added a subscriber and a callback method which sets vx vy etc variables... The problem is the odom and base_link frames no longer exists.. ? I dont know whats wrong :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33390/after-execution-call-back-function-program-doesnt-return-to-orignal-execution?/) by [anonymous2029](https://answers.ros.org/users/2029/anonymous2029/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-05-06**:
We need more details. Do you call ros::spin or ros::spinOnce anywhere? Could you generate a minimal example that has the same issue or post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are asking about doing callbacks in ROS, use ros::spinOnce() instead of ros::spin() in your while loop. See this tutorial: [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

---

Originally posted by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) with karma: 2268 on 2012-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-06**:
The odometry sample program mentioned above did not call ros::spinOnce(). It should, so I fixed it.